# Using pre-populated drop down list in PHP to send output to INSERT

Tags: php, mysql, html, forms

I am creating a form which when submitted sends the output to an INSERT statement. I am learning how to do this using:

```
<form action="somepage.php" method="post">
Example: <input type="text" name="something" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

I am fairly comfortable doing this and then writing an INSERT statement containing $_POST.

I also have a field that I would like to present in a drop down which is populated with the results of a mysql_query, as below:

```
$sql = "SELECT name FROM customer";
$result4 = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<select name='name'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result4)) {
echo "<option value='" . $row['name'] . "'>" . $row['name'] . "</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

However I am not sure how to use the value that the user selects. I.e. I would like to use the value that they select in my INSERT statement along with the other form fields.

How do I do this?

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 1):

You specify in the `<select>` tag the name, like:

```
<select name="car">
    <option>Audi</option>
    <option>BMW</option>
</select>
```

And get the submitted value with `$_POST['car']`

In your case, after submitting you can use `$_POST['name']`

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm still a little confused though (beginner...). Where do I put the drop down code in relation to the rest of the form/submit button? How does the code send the value to somepage.php without it being specified as with action="somepage.php"?

Comment: Would this work?: <form action="somepage.php" method="post">
Example: <input type="text" name="something" />
<?php
echo "<select name='name'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result4)) {
echo "<option value='" . $row['name'] . "'>" . $row['name'] . "</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
?>
<input type="submit" />
</form>

Answer (score 0):

Use `$_POST['name']` to get the submitted value.

Comment: The problem is I don't know how to put the bits of the form together. I.e. where is the 'Submit' button? Where is the action="..."?